# Visual Studio 2008 Expression Edition Stopped Debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Out of nowhere, Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition decided to stub debugging with a certain project of mine.  I didn't add any breakpoints.  When I run the program through Other projects debug perfectly fine.  I am currently running Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit.  Has anybody else experienced this?   Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a little vague, but here are a few things to look at:

If your project stopped debugging and it is a Silverlight project, check that you have enabled the silverlight debugging (right click on project file of host web project, select Properties, Web tab, Debuggers - Silverlight checkbox at the bottom of the page).

If it is some javascript that has stopped debugging, then you cannot debug javascript while you have silverlight debugging enabled.

Also check the build type dropdown at the top of the editor - if it is set to Release then no breakpoints will be stopped on, just set it back to debug.

Comment: It works now. I restarted my computer and started up Visual Studio, it still didn't work. I left it open for about an hour or two and now it works. Weird....

It wasn't a Silverlight package nor did it contain JavaScript.  I had already checked what you said earlier and to default.  Thanks for your help though.  :)